# How can I systematically prevent misdirected email to be sent

Tags: security, email

I am working for a recruitment firm as an IT guy. as you might know recruitment firm sends and receives lots of sensitive information like resume and so on and the business requested us to come up with some solution that systematically prevents misdirected email to be sent out as misdirected email could lead our business to go downhill.

Example scenario that I would like to prevent is like this:

1. a consultant attaches a candidate's resume in email which is intended to be sent to a client John@abc.com.
2. The consultant sends this email to a client John@xyz.com.

I was thinking that if we standardize attachment's file name like below, maybe there is a system or solution that prevents this kind of scenario from happening?

-Make attachment always has recipient client's domain name (e.g. resume_abc.com)

*This needs to be done manually or by system.

with this standardized file name, I was thinking of like this:

A consultant attaches a resume named candidate_abc.com and send email to John@xyz.com

System or solution will check the attachement's file name and the recipient's domain and compare two if the attachment has the matching domain in the file name. if the matching domain is found in the file name, allowed to be sent, if not, blocked or show a pop up to make the sender to confirm if it is really ok to be sent out.

My questions to security professionals here are the followings:

is there such system or solution described above to prevent misdirected email?

How does your company prevents this type of misdirected email from happening?

Is there any other good ways to prevent this type of misdirected email?

I appreciate your comments and opinions on this :)

Cheers,

Comment: And what if the naming convention isn't followed? And how would you handle the inevitable exceptions to every rule? You couldn't block *all* attachments. Seems like the problem you're trying to fix is more of a training issue than anything else. A better way to manage this would be to have software that generates these kinds of e-mails automatically: the consultant matches a candidate with a customer in the program and the resume (or a link to it) is attached and sent by the program, not relying on the consultant to input or attach anything at all, other than a personalized message.

Comment: I'd completely avoid using email for sensitive information and use some kind of portal with access control and audit logging, instead.